# How to use LES in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I have to create COM file and use LES there. I didn't find any examples of using LES, only this one.
And there is an error **"operand types do not match"** in the string `LES BX, VIDEO`
What should I do? I thought we can use register bx for LES.

```
.model  tiny
.code
ORG 100h
start:                                 
LES BX, VIDEO ; ES = B800h (memory VGA), BX = 72Eh      
MOV AX, 0         ; reset registers
MOV ES, AX        ; ES = 0
MOV BX, AX        ; BX = 0

MOV BX, VIDEO     ; analog of using LES
MOV ES, VIDEO+2   ; with using two commands MOV
                ; ES = B800h (memory VGA), BX = 72Eh
RET               ; exit

VIDEO DW 72Eh
DW 0B800h
END start
```

Comment: Which assembler do you use?  What are you trying to achieve with that `les` instruction?

Comment: What assembler are you using? MASM? Tasm? something else? What version?

Comment: @fuz I think he's trying to load `ES:BX` with `B800:072E` to write to video memory

Comment: @puppydrum64 This is one possible interpretation of what OP is doing.  However, previous experience with beginner questions has made me stop inferring author intent unless clearly and exactly given.

Answer (score 2):

The `LES` instruction is used with a **dword** memory operand. Your instruction `LES BX, VIDEO` refers to a **word** memory operand because *VIDEO* is followed by a `DW` (define word) directive. That is why you get the error "operand types do not match".

You can change this:

```
VIDEO DW 72Eh
      DW 0B800h
```

into

```
VIDEO DD 0B800h:072Eh
```

And of course the code that follows:

```
MOV AX, 0         ; reset registers
MOV ES, AX        ; ES = 0
```

will destroy what you just loaded in the `ES` segment register!

Comment: `VIDEO DD 0B800h:072Eh` may work with TASM, but I don't think it works for some versions of MASM

Comment: As I recall the more universal way was `VIDEO LABEL DWORD`
`DW 0b800h`  `DW 72Eh`

Comment: Oops in my last comment I had the offset and segment reversed. Should have been `DW 72Eh` `DW 0b800h` or `DW 72Eh, 0b800h`